# Form validations with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do validations with js, i have an input and a select, each one has an alert under it, those alerts appear when the input's value is less than 12, and when the user leaves the select empty, and there is a disabled  button at the end of the form, it gets enabled if the value of the input == 12 or the select is not null, i tried something for the input only but i can't figure out how to put the select condition in the same function, here is my code:

```js
$('#requiredInput').keyup(function () {
  if ( document.getElementById("requiredInput").value.length == 12)
         {
           document.getElementById("requiredAlert").style.display = 'none';
           document.getElementById("disabledButton").disabled = false;

         } else if (       document.getElementById("requiredInput").value.length != 12 ) {
           document.getElementById("requiredAlert").style.display = 'block';
           document.getElementById("disabledButton").disabled = true;
         }
});
```

```css
p{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="requiredInput">
<p id="requiredAlert">Please fill out this field</p>

<select id="requiredSelect">
<option>Hi</option>
</select>
<p id="requiredSelectAlert">Please select</p>

<button disabled id="disabledButton">Submit</button>
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the select? You want if the select isn't null do something?

Comment: @MarioJuniorTorresPerez yes, the button get enabled if the select isn't null and the input's value == 12, else the alerts should appear and the button stays disabled

Answer (score 0):

You could add to the condition... Something like:

```
$('#requiredInput').keyup(function () {
   if (document.getElementById("requiredInput").value.length == 12 || document.getElementByid("requiredSelect").value != "Hi")
      {
        document.getElementById("requiredAlert").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("disabledButton").disabled = false;
      } else if (document.getElementById("requiredInput").value.length != 12 && document.getElementByid("requiredSelect").value == "Hi") {
        document.getElementById("requiredAlert").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("disabledButton").disabled = true;
      }
});
```

and add to your htm:

```
<select id="requiredSelect">
  <option value='Hi'>Hi</option>
  <option value='op1'>option 1</option>
  <option value='opN'>option N</option>
</select>
```

On the other hand, you are using jQuery so you could change you code to:

```
$('#requiredInput').keyup(function () {
   if ($("#requiredInput").val().length == 12 || $("#requiredSelect").val() != "Hi")
      {
        $("#requiredAlert").css("display" : "none");
        $("#disabledButton")prop("disabled", false);
      } else if ($("#requiredInput").val().length != 12 && $("#requiredSelect").val() == "Hi") {
        $("#requiredAlert")css("display" : 'block');
        $("#disabledButton")prop("disabled", true);
      }
});
```

Comment: You meant `$("#requiredInput")` with a `#`

Comment: Yes, I did, I update the code to reflect it, sorry about it, now is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have the select with a null value selected by default, you have to add one more option in the top. You can add `<option selected disabled>Select Something</option>`. The `disabled` attribute will make it unselectable by the user after they click another option.

Then we need to add values to the options. Add an empty value in the default option we added before so it becomes `<option selected disabled value="">Select Something</option>`. Then, when the field change event fires, you can check the value of the select field and make the magic happen. I have updated your snippet bellow and added the above advice.

```js
$('#requiredInput').keyup(function () {
  if ( document.getElementById("requiredInput").value.length == 12)
         {
           document.getElementById("requiredAlert").style.display = 'none';
           document.getElementById("disabledButton").disabled = false;

         } else if (       document.getElementById("requiredInput").value.length != 12 ) {
           document.getElementById("requiredAlert").style.display = 'block';
           document.getElementById("disabledButton").disabled = true;
         }
});

$('#requiredSelect').change(function () {
    if ( document.getElementById("requiredSelect").value != "")
         {
           document.getElementById("requiredSelectAlert").style.display = 'none';
           document.getElementById("disabledButton").disabled = false;

         } else if ( document.getElementById("requiredSelect").value === "" ) {
           document.getElementById("requiredSelectAlert").style.display = 'block';
           document.getElementById("disabledButton").disabled = true;
         }
});
```

```css
p{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="requiredInput">
<p id="requiredAlert">Please fill out this field</p>

<select id="requiredSelect">
<option value="" disabled selected>Select something</option>
<option value="hi">Hi</option>
</select>
<p id="requiredSelectAlert">Please select</p>

<button disabled id="disabledButton">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of you request. Using jquery to find the :selected element and get the text into the option tag. Also in each option you can set an value and get the .val() and will works.

```js
$('#requiredInput').keyup(function () {
  if ( document.getElementById("requiredInput").value.length == 12 && $('#requiredSelect').find(":selected").text() != "default")
         {
           document.getElementById("requiredAlert").style.display = 'none';
           document.getElementById("disabledButton").disabled = false;

         } else if (       document.getElementById("requiredInput").value.length != 12 && $('#requiredSelect').find(":selected").text() == "default") {
           document.getElementById("requiredAlert").style.display = 'block';
           document.getElementById("disabledButton").disabled = true;
         }
         
         
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="requiredInput">
<p id="requiredAlert">Please fill out this field</p>

<select id="requiredSelect">
<option>default</option>
<option>hi</option>
</select>
<p id="requiredSelectAlert">Please select</p>

<button disabled id="disabledButton">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I prefer to add the `value` to the `<option>` because sometimes the text() could be replaced by user configuration or translation services, but the value remains the same.